# Implicit conversion from nil to hash with refine bug

Tags: ruby, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I try to made a little hack with the refine feature (i use ruby 2.1.0)

The purpose is to redirect the implicit conversion (to_hash) to the explicit conversion and avoid this error :

```
data = {test: :t}.merge!(nil) 
# Return TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash
```

When i reopen the NilClass all is ok  :

```
class NilClass
 def to_hash
   to_h
 end
end
data = {test: :t}.merge!(nil) 
# { :test => :t }
```

When i use refine feature, i get a no method error.

```
module MyRefine
  module NilClass
    refine ::NilClass do
      def to_hash
        selt.to_h
      end
    end
  end
end

module Aer
  using MyRefine::NilClass 
  data = {test: :t}.merge!(nil)
  puts data
end
# NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `to_hash' for nil:NilClass
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: How about using an empty hash as a fallback, so you wouldn't need to path `NilClass`: `data = {test: :t}.merge!(nil || {})`

Comment: This is a minimalist example reproducing the problem.
The main idea is to extend NilClass just to avoid to write this code.
And refine feature allows me to do this more cleanly than extending directly NilClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refinements are lexically scoped. They are only visible inside of the script, module declaration or class declaration that you activate them in. That's the whole *purpose* of them.

In your case, you use the refinement inside of the `Aer` module declaration, which means that inside of that module declaration, `NilClass` will have a `to_hash` method. But *only* inside of that module. And *not* inside any other module or class, *including* `Hash`, where `merge!` is defined.

Comment: This was what i expected at first but the error is different when i use the refine and don't use refine. How can it be?

Comment: My guess is that it's an implementation artifact, leaking private internal implementation details of how YARV implements refinements under the hood.

Comment: But the main point is: the *whole point* of refinements is that those monkey patches are *not* visible to other code.